# sql query between two values desc

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that has two fields `start_interval` and `end_interval` both storing `int` values that represent hours.  I'm using this query to select records from that table:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE 23 BETWEEN start_interval AND end_interval;
```

How can I get values when the `start_interval` is greater than `end_interval`?  For exemple if `start_interval = 22` and `end_interval = 5`?

Comment: Answer to your question aside, you should set up constraints such that this condition can't ever happen.

Comment: Considering the question's mysql tag, `constraint check` is something most mysql users are not acclimatized to. I concur that constraints are a necessity to prevent bad data

Comment: Your 23 appears arbitrary... do you want only those where the net difference is 23, or net difference is from 0-23, or only those 23 or more (hours)  What is the purpose of what you are trying to find.

Comment: Perhaps I just don't get your requirements.  Is the only requirement that you're trying to find rows in which `end_interval <= start_inverval`?

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE 23 BETWEEN LEAST(start_interval, end_interval) AND
                GREATEST(start_interval, end_interval);
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this query can't solve the problem. becouse if the start_interval=22 and end_interval=5 the least will return 5 and greatest will return 22, so the 23 never will be between 5 and 22. the interval values represents the hours, so 22 represents 10PM and 5 is 5AM.

Comment: @GodFather: how about, where 23 between start_interval and if(start_interval>=end_interval,end_interval+24,end_interval)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you check for both directions:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE
  (23 BETWEEN start_interval AND end_interval) OR
  (23 BETWEEN end_interval AND start_interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
…
WHERE 23 BETWEEN start_interval AND end_interval
   OR start_interval > end_interval AND
      23 NOT BETWEEN end_interval + 1 AND start_interval - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
where 23 between start_interval and if(start_interval>=end_interval,end_interval+24,end_interval)?
```

Comment: That was my original thought too, but then I realised it wouldn't work for something like `4 BETWEEN 22 AND 5(+24)`.